# Filter to different "formats" vs "formattings"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence

I always get confused with when to use format vs formatting.

I understand that we should use formatting when we say we want to change the formatting of something.

But what about the following?

1. Filter to the different formats/formattings
2. Sort by format/formatting

Both are used as nouns. Can someone please elaborate on when would be the most appropriate to use each of these words?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to answer for these examples without knowing more about the situation.  "Format" could apply in most if not all cases, and I don't think anyone would complain if you used the shorter form. "Formatting" is more useful if you want to separate the act of applying the format from the format (=layout, template) itself.

Answer (score 1):

The **format** usually describes a kind of logical or physical container for content, as in LP or EP format (the format here describes the length of music that the item can hold). If you see a document prepared a certain way, you might say that it's in APA format. In those cases, you would not say **APA formatting** or **EP formatting**. So, in your examples:

1. Filter to the different formats (Honestly though I've never heard of **filter to...**; I have often heard/seen **filter by**.)
2. Sort by format

In both cases, what you are after is a list of items prepared a certain way (by format), or perhaps a list of the available ways to arrange items (the formats available).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Appreciate your response! Is it appropriate to say "filter column A to this format" or should it be "filter column A to show this format?" Also,  what is the most appropriate way to say I want to filter the column by various formats so that we can see what is available. Would it be "filter by the various formats?"

Comment: Sure thing. I'd say neither, but instead, "Filter column A by this format," but if you can be more specific it's better still -- for example, "Filter column A by record type." For your second question, yes.

Comment: What about "Filter by batch codes beginning with AM?"

Comment: Yes, that sounds good!